Understanding a statement of a theorem of Erdős on the convergence of power series
Here is a link for this question: https://old.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1952-09.pdf
In this article, Erdős states a pair of theorems:

Theorem 1 Let $n_1 < n_2 < \cdots$ be a sequence of integers satisfying $\liminf\limits_{k\to\infty} n_k^{\frac{1}{k}} = 1$. Then, there exists a power series $\sum_k a_k z^{n_k}$ which converges uniformly on $|z| \le 1$ but for which $\sum_k |a_k| = \infty$.


Theorem 2 Let $n_1 < n_2 < \cdots$ be a sequence of integers satisfying $\liminf\limits_{j-i\to\infty} \left( n_j -n_i \right)^{\frac{1}{j-i}} = 1$. Then, there exists a power series $\sum_k a_k z^{n_k}$ which converges uniformly on $|z| \le 1$ but for which $\sum_k |a_k| = \infty$.

He claims that Theorem 2 is stronger than Theorem 1, since if $\liminf\limits_{k\to\infty} n_k^{\frac{1}{k}} = 1$, then $\liminf\limits_{k\to\infty} (n_k - n_1)^{\frac{1}{k}} = 1$.
This seems very different to how I would usually interpret ${j-i} \to \infty$; I would usually expect that this requires $\liminf = 1$ for every $j-i \to \infty$ (including the ones where $i \not \equiv 1$) whereas Erdős seems to be using it as a condition which is satisfied if it is met for any $j-i \to \infty$.
Please could someone confirm to me that this is the case? I'm not sure how Theorem 2 is stronger than Theorem 1 otherwise.

The assumption in Thm $2$ means that there are sequences $i_k$
and $j_k$
so that $j_k−i_k\to\infty$
and $(n_{j_k}−n_{i_k})^{1/(j_k−i_k)}\to 1.$
The sequence $i_k$
is not necessarily bounded. Therefore the assumption is weaker than the one in Thm $1.$

@RyszardSzwarc Yes, I did not think the sequence $(i_k)$ would have to be bounded. What is strange for me, as I said, is that Erdős seems to be saying it is sufficient for the limit to hold for any i.e. even one choice of sequences $(i_k),(j_k)$ with $j_k - i_k \to \infty$ rather than all possible choices of sequences $(i_k),(j_k)$ with $j_k - i_k \to \infty$, which is what the notation usually implies to me.

If you find one choice of sequences  you are done as $(n_{j_k}-n_{i_k})^{1/(j_k-i_k)}\ge 1, $  so you cannot go below $1.$

@RyszardSzwarc Yes, that is true. Sorry, there were several possible errors I could have made, but I think the issue is that I have actually misinterpreted the $\liminf$ here. Looking at this again, I realise that $\liminf_{j-i}$ might actually mean $\sup_n \inf_{j-i = n}$? In which case, as you say, one choice of sequences $(i_k), (j_k)$ would indeed be sufficient. I was previously interpreting it as $\sup_k \inf_{j_k - i_k \to \infty}$.
